# Recursive Statement not Instantly Returning

Tags: java, recursion

I am creating a method that takes a list of numbers and an index.

If there is a number after the index that is six times the first number, it returns true. Otherwise, it returns false.

```
 public static boolean firstElementMultiple(int []Numbers, int index) {
        System.out.println(Numbers[index]);

        if ((Numbers[0]*6)==Numbers[index]){
            System.out.println("Yep");
            return true;
        }

        if (index+1 >= Numbers.length){
            return false;
        }


        firstElementMultiple(Numbers, index+1);

        return false;
```

With a list of {5,6,7,30} and an index of 1, false is returned, even though 30 is in the list.

6
7
30
Yep

Is printed, which shows me that it did recognise that 30 was in the list. However, it is still returning false even though the next statement is true and should stop the method?

This has to be done by recursion.

edit: I have to put the 'return false;' at the end as, without it, it doesn't let me. However, I don't see how it can ever get there because there is always a recursive call in the way.

Comment: Perhaps return the result of your recursive call instead of just a bunch of `return false`/`return true;`?

Comment: The recursion is a call to itself. In your case, at some point you method should call itself.

You need to make sure you can meet your ending condition(s) as well (hence returning false or true at some point).

My guess is you probably want to return a call to your method after testing your ending conditions :)

(Btw, depending on your initial parameter you might get a stackoverflow error which is kind of "meta" here :D)

Answer (score 1):

```
firstElementMultiple(Numbers, index+1);
return false;
```

Here's the end of your method. This is what it does. It says "Call `firstElementMultiple` to keep looking for the value we're looking for. Once you've finished looking, completely ignore whether or not you found it and return `false` anyway."

Given that, how can you fix it to do what you want it to do, namely *return* whether or not we found the element?

Comment: But isn't a return statement supposed to return immediately and not wait until the end of the recursion?

Comment: Yes, a `return` statement returns from the current function, not from *all* of the functions. Imagine if a `return` statement returned from every function in the whole program; then the first return in your program would end `main` and terminate the program.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the end, you are returning false in your recursive function no matter what you get in further calculations. You should change your code to this:

```
public static boolean firstElementMultiple(int []Numbers, int index) {
    System.out.println(Numbers[index]);

    if ((Numbers[0]*6)==Numbers[index]){
        System.out.println("Yep");
        return true;
    }

    if (index+1 >= Numbers.length){
        return false;
    }

    return firstElementMultiple(Numbers, index+1);
}
```

Basically you need to change

```
firstElementMultiple(Numbers, index+1);
return false;
```

to

```
return firstElementMultiple(Numbers, index+1);
```

Comment: This does not work because I get the "missing return statement" error.